# How do I read output from another program with C#?

Tags: c#, console

I would like to take the output from one program, called Testing.exe, and print it using another program.

The output of Testing.exe is as follows.

> Printing number: 7
>
> Printing number: 7

The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static int printNumber(int numberToPrint)
        {
            numberToPrint = 7;
            Console.WriteLine("Printing number: " + numberToPrint.ToString());
            return numberToPrint;
        }
    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = 5;
            number = printNumber(number);
            Console.WriteLine("Printing number: " + number.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Supposedly I can use the Process class and RedirectStandardOutput, but I can't figure out how to use them...

How do I take the output above, and print it from another application? I am trying to take input from a console application and put it into another application.

I am just starting to learn to program, so I am lost.

Comment: You are right about using `RedirectStandardOutput`. What specifically are you having problems with? Take a look at this small example. It should help you out: http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput

Comment: FYI: instead of writing `Console.WriteLine("Printing number: " + numberToPrint.ToString());` you can put `Console.WriteLine("Printing number: {0}", numberToPrint);`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I've tried the program on that website, but when I run it, replacing "C:\7za.exe" with "Testing.exe" (keeping in mind that Testing.exe is in the same directory as the RedirectStandardOutput program) I just get a blank console window. The output from Testing.exe is not shown.

Comment: Can you remove the `Console.ReadKey()` from the Testing.exe application and try again? Or better yet, review Sean's answer and note how he reads the Output prior to waiting for the process to exit (which it might not if it is waiting for user input).

Comment: @KevinAnderson I removed that, and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

```
 // Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx